# Timezone setting in Linux

Tags: linux, date, time, time-zone

I'm setting timezone GMT+6 on my Linux machine by copying the zoneinfo file to `/etc/localtime`, but the date command is showing the time UTCtime-6. What is the reason for this behaviour?

I'm assuming the date command should display UTCtime+6 time. Here are steps I'm following:

```
date
Wed Jan 22 17:29:01 IST 2014

date -u
Wed Jan 22 11:59:01 UTC 2014

cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT+6 /etc/localtime

date
Wed Jan 22 05:59:21 GMT+6 2014

date -u
Wed Jan 22 11:59:01 UTC 2014
```

Comment: The date shows GMT+6, the same zone as the zone you copied to /etc/localtime.

Comment: @mockinterface: You are right but why date command is showing time less then UTC time?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question. It has the entire set of IST/GMT+6/UTC-6/UTC+6 time zones mentioned plus the two date commands that you refer to as "a date command" - please be exact.

Comment: I think it's clear enough.  OP has India standard time set, and it's 17:29 in India which means it's 11:59 UTC.  then OP changes just the time zone by that `cp` command; the UTC isn't affected (as we can see), but the localized time now is 5:59 GMT+6 although it should be 17:59 GMT+6.

Comment: Some kind of 12/24 hrs problem? `17 == 05 PM` ?

Comment: BTW, this is not a programming question, is it? Migrate to ServerFault or Unix&Linux?

Comment: Maybe it is.  Depends on the answer.

Comment: Try `date +"%R p %Z"` to see if it's an AM/PM issue and which time zone the date command assumes.

Comment: This Q was cross posted on U&L as well: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110522/timezone-setting-in-linux

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Zones like `Etc/GMT+6` are intentionally reversed for backwards compatibility with POSIX standards.  See the comments [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area), and in [this file from the tzdb](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/etcetera).

You should almost never need to use these zones. Instead you should be using a fully named time zone like `America/New_York` or `Europe/London` or whatever is appropriate for your location. Refer to the *[List of tz database time zones on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm using GMT+ format in my embedded system  and found this type of behavior

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at.  You asked why it was reversed, and this is why.

Comment: A time zone is not the same thing as a *time zone offset*. You aren't just setting `+6`, you're setting `Etc/GMT+6` which is a very specific entry in the zoneinfo data which means "6 hours West of GMT", which in common usage is `-6`.  If you really want `+6` then you should set a zone like `Etc/GMT-6`, or you can use a named zone that has a +6 offset.  See also the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).